# tExtractDelimited Talend gives empty column header

Tags: split, talend

Talend rookie here.
I succed to split a column "category" based on "/" delimiter using tExtractDelimited. However it din't give me correct header name as I have entered in the schema. TFileInputExcel & tFileOutputExcel file.

expected result **:
[image]

instead i get this :
[image]

or if i checked the option with "include header" in tFileOutputExcel, it gave me this :
[image]

any idea how to get the expected result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to let as you done but in your `tExtractDelimitedFields` you put as below[image]

Output :

```
.----------+----------+----------.
 |           tLogRow_19           |
 |=---------+----------+---------=|
 |category_1|category_2|category_3|
 |=---------+----------+---------=|
 |ABC       |123       |apple     |
  '----------+----------+----------'
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for answering Amine Ben Khelifa. I have my TExtractDelimited setting correct (the same as you suggested) but it wasn't the problem actually.Instead I forgot to change the value in the otion header for tFileInputExcel. When I change this to 1 instead of 0, it solved my problem. Working with french version of TOS has made it less evident for me.
[image]

Comment: Mark solution as solved ,if it helped .  Thanks